# Network interface is not ready until I try and bring it up

Tags: linux, networking, init, yocto

My network interface does not come up when I boot.  This was happening with systemd, and I switched to sysv (which I know better) and it's still happening.

This is after I boot, no matter how long I wait:

```
root@imx8mq-var-dart:~# ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Then when I try and bring the interface up, I get this:

```
root@imx8mq-var-dart:~# ifup eth0
Atheros 8031 ethernet 30be0000.ethernet-1:00: attached PHY driver [Atheros 8031 ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=30be0000.ethernet-1:00, irq=POLL)
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
root@imx8mq-var-dart:~# 
fec 30be0000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
```

Then this:

```
root@imx8mq-var-dart:~# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr F8:DC:7A:29:37:0B
          inet addr:10.1.10.95  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fadc:7aff:fe29:370b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:700 (700.0 B)  TX bytes:1688 (1.6 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

My understanding is that "eth0: link is not ready" is not normal.  It's like the interface isn't ready yet, and then something about trying to bring it up kicks it in to gear and makes it ready.

Anybody know what might be going on here?

Current /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 10.1.10.95
        gateway 10.1.0.1
        netmask 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: the message (which isn't an error) you see is about ipv6 is probably not relevant to your problem. But you have to provide your configuration (file interfaces etc.)   for your problem to be answerable.

Comment: Added /etc/network/interfaces file

Comment: I admit I don't see what's wrong, except maybe if the device for the interface gets added too late (eg if it's some usb device) . In such case  adding `allow-hotplug eth0` would help.